# How should I mention my affiliation while sending a paper to a journal?

Tags: publications, journals, paper-submission, affiliation

This is my first experience in sending a paper to a journal and I'm not sure how I should mention my affiliation.

In the guide for authors of the journal, it is stated that:

> Please clearly indicate the given name(s) and family name(s) of each author and check that all names are accurately spelled. Present the authors' affiliation addresses (where the actual work was done) below the names. Indicate all affiliations with a lowercase superscript letter immediately after the author's name and in front of the appropriate address. Provide the full postal address of each affiliation, including the country name and, if available, the e-mail address of each author.

Can someone write an example please?

Comment: What's unclear about those (actually very detailed) instructions? You can probably find examples in other papers published by that journal.

Answer (score 2):

The affiliation is simply the name of your research group, department, and university. Usually, the address is included too. In some countries, laboratories have a unique identification number and they always want to make sure it is mentioned so they can do their own statistics on the number of published papers. This is also the reason why some PIs want the name of the lab to be written in a certain pre-defined format. To make a long story short: **(1) ask your PI** how he / his university want it. If for some reason this is not an option, simply **(2) look at other papers published in the journal** you are submitting to and do the same.